# Proof with compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

Prove the following: If $\Omega$ is open, then there are compact sets $K_j,j = 1,2,...,$ with
$$K_j \subset \mathring{K}_{j+1} \quad \text{for every j} $$
such that $$ \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j = \Omega$$

Problem is that I have no idea how to chose these compact sets $K_j$; someone who can give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Are you working over $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I'm working over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Kabouter9 Then you should add this information to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\Omega = \mathbb C$ it is trivial: Take $K_n = \overline{B_n(0)}$.

So let us consider $\Omega \ne \mathbb C$. For each $z \in \Omega$ define $r(z) =  \sup \{r > 0 \mid B_r(z) \subset \Omega \}$. Since  $\Omega \ne \mathbb C$ we have $r(z) < \infty$. Clearly $B_{r(z)}(z) \subset \Omega$.

Let $\Omega' \subset \Omega$ be the subset of all $z = x + iy \in \Omega$ such that $x, y \in \mathbb Q$. This set is countable since $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ is countable. Write $\Omega' = \{ z_1, z_2, z_3, \ldots ... \}$. Let us show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{r(z_n)}(z_n) = \Omega$.

Consider $z \in \Omega$. There exists $n$ such that $\lvert z - z_n \rvert < r(z)/2$. For $w \in \mathbb C$ with $\lvert w - z_n \rvert < r(z)/2$ we have $\lvert w - z \rvert \le \lvert w - z_n \rvert + \lvert z_n - z \rvert < r(z)/2 + r(z)/2 = r(z)$, thus $B_{r(z)/2}(z_n) \subset B_{r(z)}(z) \subset \Omega$. Hence $r(z_n) \ge r(z)/2$. But clearly $z \in B_{r(z)/2}(z_n) \subset B_{r(z_n)}(z_n)$.

Define
$$K_m = \bigcup_{n=1}^m \overline{B_{(1-\frac{1}{m})r(z_n)}(z_n)} .$$
These sets are compact. Clearly $U_m =  \bigcup_{n=1}^m B_{(1-\frac{1}{m})r(z_n)}(z_n)$ is an open set contained in $K_m$, thus $U_m \subset \mathring K_m$. Since $\overline{B_{(1-\frac{1}{m})r(z_n)}(z_n)} \subset B_{(1-\frac{1}{m+1})r(z_n)}(z_n)$, we see that $K_m \subset U_{m+1} \subset \mathring K_{m+1}$. Let us show that $\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty K_m = \Omega$.

Consider $z \in \Omega$. There exists $N$ such that $z \in B_{r(z_N)}(z_N)$. For sufficiently large $M$ we have $z \in B_{(1-\frac{1}{M})r(z_N)}(z_N)$, thus for $m = \max (N, M)$ we get $z \in K_m$.

Comment: Thanks! After seeing this, I am convinced that I could not find this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\Omega$ is non-empty.

Hint: Suppose you have constructed $K_j$, consider the Hausdorff distance of $K_j$ and $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega$ i.e. let $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $K$ is compact and $C$ is closed, the Hausdorff distance between $K$ and $C$ denoted by $D(K,C)$ is defined as

$$D(K,C) = \underset{x \in K, y\in C}{\min}(d(x,y)).$$

Use this to build the interior of the next compact set.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. For simplicity, we will consider the bounded open subsets first.

(In fact, we may assume $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. The same argument works.)  Take a countable dense subset $D=\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of $\Omega$, that is, $\overline{D}\cap\Omega=\Omega$.
For each $n$, choose $r_n$ such that $\overline{B}(x_n,r_n)\subseteq \Omega$.

There is no reason to think $X=\bigcup_n \overline{B}(x_n,r_n)$ is $\Omega$. Hence we need a trick: observe that every subset of $\Omega$ is second-countable, so Lindelöf. Hence we can choose a collection of closed balls $\{\overline{B}(y_n,t_n)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that $\overline{B}(y_n,t_n)\subseteq\Omega$ and $\{B(y_n,t_n/2)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ covers $\Omega\setminus X$.

Now construct $K_n$ as follows: assume that $K_{n-1}$ is given. Consider a collection $\mathcal{X}$ of a countable cover of closed balls that covers $\partial K_{n-1}$. Now define $K_n:=K_{n-1}\cup \bigcup \mathcal{X}\cup \overline{B}(x_n,r_n)\cup \overline{B}(y_n,t_n)$. We can see that $K_n$ satisfies the desired properties.

---

Now consider the general $\Omega$. Assume that $\langle K_{mn}\mid m\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ is a sequence of closed sets which satisfies $K_{mn}\subseteq K_{m+1,n}^\circ$ and $\bigcup_m K_{mn}=\Omega\cap B(0,n)$.
Then we can take $K_l=\bigcup_{m,n\le l} K_{m,n}$, and $\langle K_l\mid l\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ is a desired sequence.